# Why ajax works only for homepage?

Tags: cakephp

I have baked new project. My simple ajax function inserted to `..\templates\Pages\home.php`:

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "myTest.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

My `myTest.txt` is in `..\webroot\` location.

Why this works for homepage, but not for any other created site in project? For all sites except homepage cakePHP can not find my text file. I have tried various locations for this file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "/myTest.txt" for the URL to open. Without the `/` on the front, it is interpreted as a relative URL, so if you're at something like `/page/2`, then it will look for `/page/myTest.txt`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take HTTP_ROOT as constant in bootstrap.php holding the base url(site name without sub path).
2. define the `<base href="<?= HTTP_ROOT;?>" />` on the layout->head section. this will help to hit the site without sub-path on ajax request.
3. you can take a further constant eg-"siteURL" in javascript inline code on the layout's `<head>` OR a hidden input holding the base path.
4. Use the constant if you need.
   siteURL+(if any further dir under webroot)+'myTest.txt'